# Converting yaml file to json in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, yaml

I have a `edit.yml` file in my project. Here is the `yaml` file:

```
color :
  white : &color-white "#FFFFFF"
  black : &color-black "#262626"
neutral :
  20 : &color-neutral-20 "#222222"
  90 : &color-neutral-90 "#EEEEEE"
```

So when I convert this to `json` using `node.js` following code, am not getting `&color-white`. That may be because its omitting special characters while converting. But I need them in my `json`.

`node.js` code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const yaml1 = require('js-yaml');
const YAML = require('yamljs');
module.exports = {
  save : function(item) {
    fs.writeFile('edit1.yml',YAML.stringify(item,4),function(err,item){
      if(err) {
      }
    });
  },
  load : function() {
    var data = yaml1.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('edit0.yml','utf8'));
    var indentedJson = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    return indentedJson;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The YAML modules are working properly, the problem is with your YAML. It is a valid file, but maybe it is not what you want.

Let me quote a part of the YAML spec:

> Repeated nodes (objects) are first identified by an anchor (marked
>   with the ampersand - “&”), and are then aliased (referenced with an
>   asterisk - “*”) thereafter.

In your example, `color-white` is an alias for that node, that could be used in the rest of the `yaml` file.

If you need the texts after the ampersand (`&`) symbol to be in the JSON file, you could use a `yaml` file like:

```
color :
  white : "&color-white \"#FFFFFF\""
  black : "&color-black \"#262626\""
neutral :
  20 : "&color-neutral-20 \"#222222\""
  90 : "&color-neutral-90 \"#EEEEEE\""
```

That will return a JSON like:

```
{
    "color": {
        "white": "&color-white \"#FFFFFF\"",
        "black": "&color-black \"#262626\""
    },
    "neutral": {
        "20": "&color-neutral-20 \"#222222\"",
        "90": "&color-neutral-90 \"#EEEEEE\""
    }
}
```

So `json.color.white` will be `&color-white "#FFFFFF"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. will that be a valid Yaml if we do so?

Comment: Yes, sure, the values are strings, that contains escaped quotes, everything is OK

Comment: A simpler and more readable option would be to escape the initial `&` characters with a backslash: `white : \&color-white "#FFFFFF"`

Answer (score 0):

You YAML in your file is a document that contains [anchors](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor//).

Such anchors are normally used to be able to dump direct or indirect self-referential structures. Your example however does not contain aliases that refer to these anchors.

The important part of the YAML specification is within the section linked to above:

> Otherwise, anchor names are a serialization detail and are discarded once composing is completed

So anchor names should not be relied upon to be available after loading, and not used to relay information. It is the same with comments in YAML documents.

IMO you don't think you need the string `color-white` that is part of the anchor `&color-white`. You should compose that string from the key `color` by 
walking over the keys of the mapping that is the value associated with `color`. That will be `white` and `black`, and you can easily create the strings `color-white` and `color-black` from those key combinations (and find the associated color values).

That way you don't have to change the YAML document, which you might not have complete control over, and you don't have to do special parsing of a string `"&color-neutral-20 \"#222222\""` as @greuze suggests you should do.